# Question on Latex related to nested arrays

Tags: arrays

I'm having problems displaying on Math StackExchange the Latex generated by and exported from Mathematica corresponding to the following image associated with the definition of a Piecewise function which is exported in Latex as nested arrays.

---

[image: Mathematica Definition]

---

Here's the Latex generated by and exported from Mathematica:

---

```
$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \Im\left(1-2 n^s\right)<0 \\
 -1 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
 & \Re\left(1-2 n^s\right)<-1 \\
 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & \Im\left(1-2 n^s\right)>0 \\
 1 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
 & \Re\left(1-2 n^s\right)>+1 \\
 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \Im\left(1-2 n^s\right)<0 \\
 -1 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$
```

---

Math StackExchange complains about "Missing \end{array}" as illustrated in the following image.

---

[image: Missing End Array Image]

---

I've had success with displaying on Math StackExchange Latex generated by and exported from Mathematica for less complicated arrays.

---

> **Question**: Is there a problem with the Latex generated by and exported from Mathematica, or is there a problem with the MathJax rendering of this Latex on Math StackExchange?

Comment: note mathjax doesn't use tex so is mosly off topic unless you can frame the question to include latex as well, but probably removing the blank lines will help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the suggestion. Deleting the blank lines fixed the problem!